# How to check if inbound port is in use

Tags: sockets, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm developing Firefox addon that communicate with external program by sockets. This program create local socket server on specified port when this addon need it. I would like to ckeck from this addon whether this application has opened this port already.

On Win7 when server isn't created yet I receive in socket created by addon NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in nsIRequestObserver::onStopRequest but if I can feel certain port isn't open when I receive this error?

Answer (score 3):

You try to connect and see if the connection succeeds.
If it doesn't, then the port is not reachable (open).
That's the most obvious and easiest answer.

Other low-level solutions would require polling the OS itself somehow. That would be cross platform specific (so you'd need to write an implementation per platform) and also there is no API readily available so you'd have to mess around with C/C++ or at least js-ctypes, or hack together some ugly "execute this program and check output" stuff. All of which doesn't worth the fuzz.

Comment: So if it isn't easy I will try connect several times after received connection refused error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out which "inbound ports" are in use in windows you can use cmd,

if you don't know how to open cmd - open the run dialog by pressing windows-key+r. type cmd and hit enter

type `netstat -a` and hit enter and it will list all "listening" ports.

more info - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/list-open-ports-and-listening-services/

Comment: Maybe I didn't pointed this explicit before but this addon is developed by me and I want know this from the addon (e.g. using XPCOM). Using external binary to do this could be solution but it would create additional dependencies.